# How to calculate limit of the following integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{x}\int_{x}^{2x}e^{-t^{2}}dt$$ What is the value?

Comment: **Hint :** Define $f(x)=\int_0^x e^{-t^2}dt$. What is $f'(x)$ ? Can you rewrite your limit in terms of $f'(0)$ ?

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: I was not having any idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

Use l´Hopital's rule and Fundamental Theorem of Calculus:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\int_x^{2x}e^{-t^2}dt}x=\lim_{x\to0}\left(2e^{-(2x)^2}-e^{-x^2}\right)$$

Comment: It's not L'Hospital's rule, it is the simple definition of the derivative.